# Where does the Alt+F2 use as the current working directory?

Tags: 13.04

Suppose I have `/home/myusername/somedir/somefile`.

When I use Alt+F2 and type `gedit ~/somedir/somef<tab>` it can tab complete this for me to `gedit ~/somedir/somefile`.  But then I run the command, and it doesn't open my file it is just a blank editor.

On the other hand, if I use `gedit somedir/somef<tab>` it doesn't complete, and neither does `gedit ./somedir/somef<tab>`, but if I fill in the ...`ile` and then run the command, it DOES load up my file contents.

This seems inconsistent, where does Alt+F2 actually start from?

Comment: Oddly, on 13.04, I can't tab-complete the alt-F2 box (tab switches focus to the "Results" option on the menu) - but `gedit ~/foo/bar` works entirely as expected here.

Comment: I am using GNOME not unity, maybe that's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Execute `touch TESTING` and find the file. It is created in home directory.

Comment: and why doesn't `touch ~/TESTING` work?

Comment: Maybe `~` is not interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple script somewhere in your $PATH that allows you to find this out. Essentially it sends the output of any command to a notification in the top corner of your screen.

Paste the following into, e.g., `/usr/bin/send_command_output` (this should work in any folder in your `$PATH` but I saved it here):

```
#!/bin/bash

info=$(eval "$*" 2>/dev/null)
notify-send -t $((1000+300*`echo -n $info | wc -w`)) -u low -i gtk-dialog-info "$*" "$info" || exit 2
```

then run `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/send_command_output` to make it executable.

After this, in the alt-F2 box, type `send_command_output pwd`. You should see something like this:
[image]

So in my case the default directory is `~`.

Source for script: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=2848